# python - ctypes error with mysql c

Tags: python, c, linux

I create a library with c, but when I call the library in python shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "probrar_lib.py", line 6, in <module>
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/msorjas/Documentos/pruebas_c/lib1.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/msorjas/Documentos/pruebas_c/lib1.so: undefined symbol: mysql_query
```

the c library, compiled with the following code:

```
gcc -c -fPIC lib1.c
gcc -shared lib1.o -o lib1.so
```

as it should compile?

I use linux.

**SOLVED:**

```
gcc -c -fPIC lib1.c
gcc -shared lib1.o -o lib1.so $(mysql_config --libs) $(mysql_config --cflags)
```

Comment: You should post the `SOLVED` bit as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc -c -fPIC lib1.c
gcc -shared lib1.o -o lib1.so $(mysql_config --libs) $(mysql_config --cflags)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell it to build against MySQL.

```
gcc -shared -lmysqlclient lib1.o -o lib1.so
```